# How do you edit a page from a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to add a button to the page when it loads from a Chrome Extension. I've managed to get it to execute when visiting a specific page, however I can't seem to be able to change any elements.

This is my listener:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete' && tab.active) {
       // code
    }
})
```

I've tried using both document.getElementById and tab.getElementById but I can't seem to edit the page at all. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **content scripts** for any manipulation with DOM on page. These scripts could be specified in manifest file. [it's described here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)

Also it could be done from background script. You will need background script anyway if some communication between your extension and webpage is needed. It's some kind of proxy.
From background script it could be attached this way:
`chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: 'content-script.js'});`